# How to get only text in div Tag except child element by Python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get a text in the div tag by selenium
I want to get a text "APPLE".
this is the web site HTML

```
<div class="detail">
            <div class="fr-view fr-view-article"> APPLE <span style="color:#999999;"> BANANA </span></div>            </div>
```

So I wrote this code

```
content = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="BoardDelForm"]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div').text
```

xpath for

```
<div class="fr-view fr-view-article">
```

then I can see the text APPLE BANANA
the child element 'BANANA' is include in the text.

So I wroth with using another xpath

```
content = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="BoardDelForm"]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/text()').text
```

then this error occured

The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id="BoardDelForm"]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

how to get a only the text APPLE in this HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code to get required text:

```
div = driver.find_element('css selector', 'div.fr-view-article')
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild;', div)['textContent'])
# ' APPLE '
```